# Restrict IDM Download from my website videos in asp.net

Tags: download, html5-video, jwplayer

Recently I recently developed a website for an institute which contains course videos. I am using to [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/) to play the videos that cannot be download. When I installed the IDM it shows a download button.

How can I restrict IDM download from my website Videos?

Answer (score 1):

You could hide the button via CSS or JavaScript. But if someone with a bit knowhow could easily bypass that. Thats the problem with clientside code. So if you want to secure remove the button from your side you have to manipulate the rendering serverside.

But may the first solution helps you ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is use secure streaming, like rtmpE - http://www.longtailvideo.com/blog/13088/securing-your-content/

Comment: Thanks for the Reply,
But i can't understand Please give any small example

Comment: You would have to use secure RTMP - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28854/using-rtmp-streaming